# Having troubles requesting querystring on serverside

Tags: c#, asp.net

So i have a querystring where i save a search value from a input textbox. When i write, what i wish to search for and press enter, i get redirected and then i have the input from the search in the querystring. I want to populate a listview using the values from the querystring. But for some reason i dont get the query string value?

Here is how i try to get the value from the querystring:

```
if (Request.QueryString["txtSearchInput"] != null)
        {
            string input = Request.QueryString["txtSearchInput"].ToString();
            SearchForItems(input);
        }
```

And here i the URL that i try to get the querystring from:
**http://localhost:46202/Users/AllProducts?ctl00%24txtSearchInput=213**
in this example i have entered 213 as the search criteria.

And last here is the inputbox where i enter the values:

```
<input runat="server" id="txtSearchInput" name="search" placeholder="GTIN, Brand or Article nr" />
```

Comment: Because the input field is a "server side" tag, the ID gets mangled to `ctl00$txtSearchInput` which then gets encoded as  `ctl00%24txtSearchInput` which is what appears in the querystring..

Comment: i deleted the runat server, the id tag and changed the querystring request to just search, like the name and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed the input box to this:

```
<input name="search" placeholder="GTIN, Brand or Article nr" />
```

and the queryrequest to this:

```
if (Request.QueryString["search"] != null)
        {
            string input = Request.QueryString["search"].ToString();
            SearchForItems(input);
        }
```

now it works. As stuartd said, the id tag messed up the querystring.